What forms a scope in javascript?
While reading about 'this' keyword and arrow function, I read: that arrow functions binds to whatever execution context the surrounding scope has.
I have attached a simple code example below.
When I tried:
const user = {
  firstName: "John",
  sayHi() {
    console.log("this in normal function", this);
    console.log(`Hello, ${this.firstName}!`);
  },
  sayHiWithArrow: () => {
    console.log("This in arrow function", this);
    console.log(`Hello, ${this.firstName} with Arrow!`);
  },
};

user.sayHi();
user.sayHiWithArrow();

in console for the arrow function in nodejs environment :
"This in arrow function {}"
Hello, undefined with Arrow!

My question is isnt scope anything that is in {} blocks, which in this case is user object?
I would like to know what forms a scope in javascript, Why isnt the object's {} considered a scope here?

"My question is isnt scope anything that is in {} blocks" yes, blocks. An object literal is not a block. Compare it with if (true) {} - can you have the exact same constructs inside the {} for the if and a {} which is an object literal? Answer is "no" you cannot, for example, have another if. Object literals are not blocks. Relevant: Self-references in object literals / initializers | Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions What does "this" refer to in arrow functions in ES6?

block statement A block statement is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of braces ("curly braces") and contains a list of zero or more statements and declarations.; scope The scope is the current context of execution in which values and expressions are "visible" or can be referenced; lexical scoping

Side note: Converting your example to use scope, it wouldn't matter if the function was an arrow or a normal function.


Why isnt the object's {} considered a scope here?

{} has several unrelated meaning in JavaScript:

blocks, which define scope (functions, for loops, etc)
object literals

Your example is an object literal. That's why it doesn't behave like a block.
